# What material would block (reflect, appear opaque) IR light 750-850nm range, but allow visible light to pass?

Tags: visible-light, infrared-radiation

I'd like to find a material, ideally a plastic, that would prevent IR light from passing , but appear as transparent  as possible to visible light. I've sampled some plascolite products and they work, but the plastic still maintains a green tint. I need something almost completely clear. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: How large does it need to be?  A shortpass filter such as [these](http://www.thorlabs.com/newgrouppage9.cfm?objectgroup_id=6082&pn=FESH0700) from Thorlabs will do the trick, but they are only 1" in diameter.

Comment: 750-850nm? That's almost visible. You're talking about some very fine tuning of absorption spectra. No wonder things appeared green

Comment: as thin as possible, and approx 6" x 12". i'll have a look at the Thorlab material, thank you for the suggestion. )

Comment: Yes it is Jimdalf. The purpose is inconspicuously prevent IR light from that specific range, from reflecting off the material behind it and back to the camera.